# How to install a browser from the command line?

Tags: debian, command-line, software-installation, browser

I installed Debian 10 with Xfce Desktop Environment. And I installed a minimum set of browsers like this:

```
$ sudo apt -y install firefox chromium
```

For development purposes I also want to install `opera`, `yandex-browser` and `google-chrome`. Previously I used a browser for this.

How can I do it from console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a script to install browsers, which consists of two parts: first add the browser repositories, and then install browsers themselfs from these repositories. `browsers.deb.sh`:

```
wget -qO - https://deb.opera.com/archive.key | sudo apt-key add

sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list <<DEBREPO
# This file makes sure that Opera Browser is kept up-to-date
# as part of regular system upgrades
deb https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free #Opera Browser (final releases)
DEBREPO

sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-developer.list <<DEBREPO
# This file makes sure that Opera Browser is kept up-to-date
# as part of regular system upgrades
deb https://deb.opera.com/opera-developer/ stable non-free #Opera Browser (final releases)
DEBREPO

wget -qO - https://repo.yandex.ru/yandex-browser/YANDEX-BROWSER-KEY.GPG | sudo apt-key add

sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser-beta.list <<DEBREPO
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.yandex.ru/yandex-browser/deb beta main
DEBREPO

wget -qO - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add

sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list <<DEBREPO
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
DEBREPO

sudo apt update
sudo apt -y install opera-stable opera-developer yandex-browser-beta google-chrome-stable
```

---

`opera-developer` `opera-stable` `yandex-browser-beta` `google-chrome-stable`

- [Manually adding the Opera APT repository](https://deb.opera.com/manual.html)
- [Installing and updating the Yandex Browser beta](https://yandex.com/support/browser-beta/about/install.html)
- [Linux Software Repositories](https://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/)